# Not able to downlad file using inappbrowser in Phonegap?

Tags: file, cordova, download, inappbrowser

I Create an App where download a file from server in mobile, so I Use InAppBrowser plugin to open download page link, its working fine but i am not able to download file using my app, when i open download link in mobile browser its automatic start download.

please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think, its better to open system browser using inAppBrowser plugin for both the platform by using

```
    window.open('http://apache.org', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

using this you can easily download.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want the user to stay in the application, I already use that code in my application, its throw user to system  browser.

Answer (score 1):

InAppBrowser doesn't allow download. You will need to modify plugin to allow it for downloading.

For android, inside `platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser`

method name `private void navigate(String url) {`

include

```
this.inAppWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

before this line `this.inAppWebView.requestFocus();`

again same code in the method `public void run() {`

after this segment

```
if (clearAllCache) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
            } else if (clearSessionCache) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie();
            }

            inAppWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

in your .java file inside onCreate

```
appView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                      startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
```

Don't know about iOS

Comment: on iOS you can't download, but some files will display on the webview and an "Open in" bar will appear. I upvote for the android part

Comment: @AtanuCSE  I try your code in my application i follow the steps but I get an error

Comment: What error? you need to add this two import `import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;` at the beginning of the java file

Comment: Till now i get error in   `inAppWebView.loadUrl(url);this.inAppWebView(error)` in inappbrowser.java

Comment: the second snippet should be `cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);` too instead pf `startActivity(i)`